# How to properly use a DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

Well, this is a very, VERY broad question. I've done a lot of research, and I'm still confused.

So, my problem is that I have a little C# program connected to an SQL database. 
Through the C# interface I can insert data into my SQL database (I know that because I checked it in MySQLWorkbench, and the data is all there), but I want to see it, so I could edit, update and erase as needed; and to that I need to use a DataGridView, but that is so, SO complicated, I've seen a lot of info, and it all confuses me a lot more.

I'm gonna do an almost-complete copypaste of my C# program:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conexion.Open();
        textBox2.Focus();
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT cveestado, nombre FROM tbestados", conexion);
            da.Fill(ds, "FillDropDown");
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "CveEstado";
            comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["FillDropDown"];
            conexion.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Guardar();
    }

    private void Guardar()
    {
        if (textBox2.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingrese un nombre", "Error");
            textBox2.Focus();
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Elija un estado", "Error");
            comboBox1.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            conexion.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbmunicipios (nombre, cveestado) values ('" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Clone();
                MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados", "Mensaje");
                conexion.Close();
                textBox2.Text = "";
                comboBox1.Text = "";
                textBox2.Focus();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

With the above I display a "Nombre" {name}, but I obtain a "Clave" {Id}, in a Combobox; and I want to do the same with my DataGridView; but I repeat, I´ve seen a lot of information, but it all confused me a lot more.

And, just to be clear, I'm gonna copy-paste my SQL code too:

```
Create table tbEstados
(
    CveEstado int not null,
    Nombre varchar (45) not null,
    Constraint pkCveEstado Primary Key (CveEstado)
)Engine=Innodb;
Create table tbMunicipios
(
    CveMunicipio int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre varchar (45) not null,
    CveEstado int not null,
    Constraint pkCveMunicipio Primary Key (CveMunicipio),
    Constraint fkCVeEdo Foreign Key (CveEstado) references tbEstados (CveEstado)
)Engine=Innodb;
```

Thanks in advance for any answers :D

Comment: bro try to write everything in English so that everyone can understand

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's a tiny mistake I made, but the logic is all there. I'll consider it for my next questions @rummykhan.

Comment: i have answered, check it and tell me is that what you were looking about..

Answer (score 1):

bro what i recommend is use `DataTable` instead of `DataSet` like this and drag a `DataGridView` on your UI

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conexion.Open();
    textBox2.Focus();
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT cveestado, nombre FROM tbestados", conexion);
        da.Fill(dt);
        //Here Comes your DataGridView
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        conexion.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

}
```

and best practice what i am doing is to call this method in `Form_Load` event